# Professor reaction to sci-hub articles

Tags: publications, legal-issues, online-publication, sci-hub

Suppose **hypothetically** I download certain new research articles from sci-hub which I read and eventually liked. Now if I contact the authors for follow up question/discussion, then is it a good idea to tell them that I read their papers through scihub (if they ask me how did I get I came across his paper).

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [Is it illegal to cite books that were illegally downloaded or accessed from a library?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13117/7734)

Comment: Even if the chance of them caring is small, why do you need to mention where you got those papers in the first place?

Answer (score 22):

I cannot tell you what authors would care in general, but I can tell you that most authors I know would not care at all. No one gets a dime from a paper anyway.

I advise you however to not mention such a detail: it's actually irrelevant in that context, because you would be writing to discuss the *content* of the paper, not the ways to get access. When you write to someone, especially someone you don't know, avoid irrelevant details: people are busy.

Comment: Also admitting that you got the paper off Scihub can get you into legal trouble (since the main difficulty with prosecution is identifying the people who're pirating the papers).

Answer (score 8):

If an author were actually curious about how you accessed their article, they would probably ask. I would suggest simply not mentioning it (since they probably don't care).

As an aside, one way to access articles behind a paywall is to contact the author directly. Many journals provide authors with links which give free access to the article.

Comment: Jup, that worked very well not only during the Elsevier blackout in a few European countries a while ago. Publishers basically love to get their articles <s>stolen</s> given away for free if the alternative is that they are not read (and later cited) at all.

Comment: Publishers' practices do sometimes seem designed to drive researchers to sci-hub.

Comment: Ignoring legality, Sci-hub has the best interface ever to get a paper. Via the publishers' sites, it's usually (1) search for title on Google (2) browse through results because it's not always the first one (3) land on a paper page with a different layout for each publisher (4) hunt for a tiny "pdf" button (5) the "pdf" button sends you to a "smart version" of the paper, ugly, slow to load and with 100% more tracking (6) hunt for another tiny "no, I really want the pdf" button (7) finally download it.

Comment: In my field, nearly every paper (or at least a preliminary version) is posted to arXiv. Publishers participate in this system since they have no option otherwise. Of course, this is preferable to sci-hub since authors themselves control whats accessible. I feel arXiv has the UX you desire (nice interface, easy pdf access), but without the issues of legality (and watermarks). I wish more disciplines systematically participated in such a preprint system.